# Back to Home directly in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, google-slides

I'm working with a WKWebView that shows a WebSite.
In the WebSite I have embedded some Google Slide but the full screen mode doesn't works on iOS (known bug from years but I can't find a solution yet) so I have to redirect at the Google Slide URL (outside of my WebSite).
The issue is that if a slide has 50 pages, and I'm at last of these, when I have to go back I'm at slide 49 and I have to go back 49 times for return to the home (every slide has a different URL).
If the slide is not in full screen and I'm at slide 50 when I go back I'm directly at the home.

How can I improve this situation? Is possible to return directly at the home also if I'm in full screen? Thanks in advance

Comment: any screenshot/code?

Comment: this is the google slide in my website https://imgur.com/QIoE5pf and this is the google slide in full screen mode (outside my website but always in my application) https://imgur.com/a/lAnvD